PCA9615DPZ burns out continuously
I need help with a problem I'm having with the PCA9615DPZ chip, a differential I2C buffer. I have two boards, both of which have this circuit:

The boards communicate with each other without problems. Each board has a DIN41612 connector and are connected to each other with a normal ethernet cable.
The problem is that already from the first boards produced, often (too often, 30-40% of the boards) the PCA9615DPZ chip burns out. All pins shorted.
I can't understand what it could depend on. Can anyone help me understand the cause and possibly find a solution?
PS: The TVS are CDSOT23-SM712

what are the connections between the boards? do they share GND? and +3V3? How are the boards powered?

The connection share only the GND. The 2 board are powered by the same 24VDC power input, then every board have their 3V3 DCDC for logic power.
